# How to change color of cell.textLabel.text (cell is a UITableViewCell) after click action

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, uicolor

I have a bunch of articles shown as cells. When a user clicks on an article, reads it and goes back, I want that cell.textlabel.text to change from a dark blue to even a darker blue to indicate that article has been read.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
if (/* article associated with cell has been read*/) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0.8 alpha:1]
}
else {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0.6 alpha:1]
}
```

Comment: Its not the color I m having w/. Its the /* article associated with cell has been read*/ part.  btw i m changing the color in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: @Dat Nguyen: You need to be more specific with your questions as it mentioned problems with the color directly.  To tell which article has been read, you need to keep track of it in some kind of data structure.  It may be a simple NSArray that keeps track of a value specifying whether or not the article at row array_index has already been read.  If you already have a data structure which represents an Article, then adding a BOOL attribute to the Article object itself would be the preferred approach.  In that case you would simply need to execute if (curArticle.isRead) { ... }